# Can I open an stoppable transaction with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I'm looking for something similiar to an SQL transaction. I need the usual protections that transactions provide, but I don't want it to slow down anyone else.

Imagine client A connects to the DB and runs these commands:

```
BEGIN TRAN
SELECT (something)
(Wait a few seconds maybe.)
UPDATE (something)
COMMIT
```

Inbetween the SELECT and the UPDATE, client B comes along and attempts to do a query, that under normal circumstances, would end up having to wait for A to COMMIT.

What I'd like is for client A to open it's transaction in such a way that should B come along and perform it's query, client A will find it's transaction immediately rolled back and it's subsequent commands failing. Client B would only experience minimal delay.

(Note that the SELECT and UPDATE are simply illustrative commands.)

Update...

I've got a high priority task (client B) that sometimes (once a month-ish) gets an SQL timeout error, and a low priority task (client A) with a transaction which causes that timeout. I'd rather that the low priority task fails and is reattempted in the next cycle.

I ended up fixing this problem by eliminating the transactions entirely and replacing them with an informal set of flags. The queries were refactored to only do something if the right set of flags are raised and I added something that cleared up abandoned records that the rollback would have cleared in the past.

I fixed my transaction issues by eliminating transactions.

Comment: If your transaction is that unimportant that you're willing to accept a rollback with subsequent commands failing, why bother with a transaction at all?

Comment: A transaction would still prevent a half-applied transaction. Of course, if you're trying to minimize time the `ROLLBACK` might take as long or longer than just completing the transaction anyway.

Comment: "What I'd like for is client A to open its transaction to client B" - that expectation does not make sense, both from a business sense and a technical viewpoint. It contradicts the basic meaning of what a transaction is.

Comment: @Joe - I might care more about not holding up high priority tasks than when my low priority task gets finished.

Comment: @blspr - Au contraire, it makes perfect sense. :)
B would in no sense get inside the transaction opened by A. It would be like if a transaction were interrupted by a network failure, the database would duitifully rollback everything that wasn't committed and release the block on the waiting query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While *not a transaction at all*, [Optimistic Concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) may be useful -- it is used by default in LINQ2SQL, etc.

The general idea is that the data is read -- modifications can be independently made -- and then the data written back with a "check" (this is loosely comparable to a Compare and Swap). If the check fails it is up the application to decide what to do (restart the process, proceed anyway, fail).

This naturally doesn't work for all scenarios and may not detect a number of interactions, such as new items added between the "read" and "write". Both the actual read and write can be in separate transactions with the appropriate isolation level; the separate transactions may allow additional transactions to be interleaved.

Of course, depending upon the exact problem and interactions... different isolation levels and/or finer grained locking may be sufficient.

Happy coding.

Comment: My series of flags (see update in question) achieves a very similar effect to what you described.

Answer (score 6):

Using `SNAPSHOT` isolation level will prevent `B` from blocking. `B` will see data in the state they were before `A` issued `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. Unless `B` modifies data, they will never block each other.

Comment: Thats a good solution. Using this isolation level, "writers don't block readers".

Answer (score 2):

That is back to front.

You can't have later clients aborting earlier transactions: that's chaos.

You can have [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28VS.80%29.aspx) so that client B has a consistent view and isn't blocked (mostly) by client A. Also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation) for more general stuff

Perhaps describe your *problem* more fully so we can offer suggestions for that...

Comment: @billpg: It isn't high priority if it runs monthly. And why do your TXNs take so long to cause timeouts. You've hacked the transactions out to hide flaws in design, queries or indexing. Or all of the above.

Comment: No, it runs every minute. A timeout failure happened monthly-ish when the worse case scenario randomly hit.

The transactions take a long time because there's a lot of processing going on over several machines on the same DB.

Comment: @billpg: increase your timeout. I misread it, but you're still hacking your transactions and data integrity for a once a month event. Anyway, it's your database, not mine...

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I've seen used (but I'm afraid that I don't have any code handy for it) is having transaction A spawn another process which then monitors the transaction. If it sees any blocks caused by the transaction then it immediately issues a `KILL` to the spid.

If I can find the code for this then I'll add it here.